# Cannot draw prediction lines

Tags: r

So I have prediction data from:

```
predictedParams <- predict(parameters, 
                           list(independentVar = log(median_income)), 
                           interval='prediction', level=0.95)

predictedParamsDataFrame <-  as.data.frame(predictedParams)

abline(independentVar, predictedParamsDataFrame$upr, lwd=4, col = 'red')
```

but that doesn't work. I've also tried doing this-

```
uprParams <- lm(independentVar ~ predictedParamsDataFrame$upr)
abline(uprParams, lwd=4, col = 'red')
```

But that results in a line that is way too high.

What should I do?

Comment: Without a reproducible example (not only code, but also sample data) it is hard to say what is going wrong here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details regarding how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`abline` draws straight lines, so it is not usually what you want to draw for other than the fit of a linear model. Also, it receives as parameters the intercept and slope, which is again not what you have here.

This will get you a matrix with the predicted values and interval:

```
predictedParams <- predict(parameters, 
                           list(independentVar = log(median_income)), 
                           interval='prediction', level=0.95)
```

Now you simply need to plot `independentVar` and the upper/lower interval:

```
lines(log(median_income), predictedParams[,"upr"], lwd=4, col = 'red')
```

See that we use the `lines` function. In the x-axis we use `log(median_income)` because it is the actual data given to `predict`, and in the y-axis we use the upper end of the interval `predictedParams[,"upr"]`.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to plot. Then use `abline`.

```
plot(concentration, signal)
res <- lm(signal ~ concentration)
abline(res)
```